# Variable used before between function for dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

This should be a very easy question.  I have never seen a variable used *before* a Between statement in a where clause, so I need to know how this code will work:

```
declare @end date
set @end = '2014-08-31'
select * from table1 where @end between StartDate and StopDate
```

I am used to seeing:

```
select * from table1 where StartDate >= @end and StopDate <= @end
```

What are the diferences between the two?

Comment: The second query is wrong, it's the other way around: StartDate <= _end and _end <= StopDate.

Comment: Your `BETWEEN` will be the same as `@end >= StartDate AND @end <= StopDate`. Please notice that this is different than your second query

Comment: Oops on the second query, but I think you guys see what I meant.  Can you tell me exactly what the first query will return?  All records with '2014-08-31' between StartDate and StopDate?

Comment: Just don't use BETWEEN for date range queries, ever. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `BETWEEN` will function identically. It's more of a preference. See the "Result Value" section in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx).

As the comments pointed out, the OP has two scenarios that aren't matching. Perhaps using `BETWEEN` would help keep you from writing the wrong logic. It's easier to write: `BETWEEN 1 AND 10` and have it be clear what your intent is.

Comment: well, I believe they're the same as what he had intended O_o

Comment: The same in intention, but not in result (check the question comments).